# Warn user on leaving page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to warn user before closing page, but only if the page is processing or uploading its data to the server. Its asp.net web application. I have used **onbeforeunload** javascript event to show the message, but it seems to be not fitting in my scenario.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.saveButton').click(function () {

                window.btnClicked = true;

            });
        });

        function closeEditorWarning() {
            if (window.btnClicked) {
                return 'It looks like you have been uploading something -- if you leave before submitting your changes will be lost.'
            }
        }
```

Comment: In what way is onbeforeunload not fitting your scenario? It sounds like exactly what you want. Make sure you set `window.btnClicked` to false when the processing/upload completes.

Comment: You must set a flag in each of your actions (file upload etc) and then check for this flag in onbeforeunload event.

Comment: yes but it should not show message on save buttons click. It should show message after save button click.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code for how you are calling closeEditorWarning().
Anyway I tried this on similar lines and it is working -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){ window.btnClicked = true; }
    );
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e){ 
    if(window.btnClicked)
        return "Are you sure, you want to leave?";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This code warns user on save button click. I do not want user to warn immediately on save button click but when the page is communicating with server.

Comment: Ok. In that case you may consider using ajax call to post data as it gives an event "beforeSend" which looks to be suitable here.